# Разный результат деления при выполнении select и return

Tags: sql, sql-server

Код хранимой процедуры:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST]

AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @X NUMERIC(2,1) = 2
    DECLARE @X2 NUMERIC(2,1) = 3
    DECLARE @Y INT  = 2
    DECLARE @X3 NUMERIC(2,1)

    SET @X3 = (@X + @X2)/@Y 

    select  @X3 AS RESULT
    RETURN @X3

END
```

При выполнении процедуры select даёт 2.5, а return 2.

Господа, почему мы имеем разницу при select и return ?

Comment: Как объявлена функция? Какой тип возвращаемых данных?

Comment: поправил описание вопроса. Теперь указано полностью, как выглядит процедура

Comment: по-моему лучше будет оформить это как функцию и указать тип возвращаемого значения явно...

Comment: Потому что оператор `RETURN` предназначен вовсе не для того, что Вы, судя по всему, предполагаете: `Процедура может возвращать целочисленное значение, называемое кодом возврата, чтобы указать состояние выполнения процедуры. Код возврата для процедуры указывается при помощи инструкции RETURN.`

Comment: Yaant, благодарю за объяснение.  Нет возможности пометить Ваш комментарий как ответ.  Оформите его пожалуйста как ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure), оператор `RETURN` предназначен для возврата **целочисленного** кода возврата, а не для возврата произвольных данных. Цитата:

> Процедура может возвращать целочисленное значение, называемое кодом
>   возврата, чтобы указать состояние выполнения процедуры. Код возврата
>   для процедуры указывается при помощи инструкции RETURN.
>
> [...]
>
> Коды возврата часто применяются в блоках управления потоком процедур для присвоения кода возврата каждой из возможных ошибок.